# BizTalk Scripting - Receive Location Schedule

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2009

I'm tasked with 2 things that I'm not seeing support for.

1. Writing a script to enable a receive location with a schedule (No
   schedule currently set)
2. Writing a script to remove a schedule from a receive location.

I see how to enable/disable a receive location, but I don't see how to manipulate the schedule via script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the below article. This may help to create script.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa559496.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Create two bindings files, one representing the receive port with schedule and one without. Then use BTSTask [importbindings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560656.aspx) command to import whichever bindings file you want.

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for scripting the scheduling of a receive location that I'm aware of.
You can achieve this in many other ways though. The simplest being to script the delivery
of the files to the receive location using shell script/etc.

Answer (score 0):

Before going down your own scripting route, I'll consider 2 options

1. Check the schedule/service window capability in Receive Location and see if it solves your problems, else
2. There is a community Scheduled task adapter, which is suitable for such activities.
   http://biztalkscheduledtask.codeplex.com/